# How to capture correlation in VUGEN from redirected response?

Tags: loadrunner

I have an issue with VUGEN that the value I want to capture is come from response of redirected request which is not sent from VUgen, is there is any way to capture the response of auto redirected request ?

I use the "web_url" function to navigate to page, the next page is need a value from which is not captured from the last page, but when I captured the requests in Fiddler, I found that the value come from auto Redirected request to that page.

Comment: Try using no redirection: `web_set_option("MaxRedirectionDepth", "0", LAST );`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had some issues with this myself, I suspect there is a bug in LR11.52 related to this. I would suggest you experiment with the `IgnoreRedirects` search filter of the `web_reg_save_param_ex` function, e.g. try with it both switched to "YES" and "NO" and see if any of those options lets you capture the value.